# error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining,

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-remote, github-for-windows

[error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikhk0.jpg)

Please I need help on how to resolve this curl 18 transfer bug.

Answer (score 0):

In my own case, I had to `$git log --oneline` to see my last commit yet to be pushed, I did hard reset and everything pushed to GitHub. The error was actually from my last commit.